# C - write() system call prints gibberish instead of pid_t

Tags: c, unbuffered-output

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t mypid = getpid();
    write(1, &mypid, sizeof(pid_t));
    return 0;
}
```

Prints gibberish instead of actual pid. Why?

Comment: Because you are not sending text to `stdout`. `write` is a binary output function. Try `printf()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`write(..`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) will not print formatted text, but rather binary output directly to a file descriptor.

Just use `printf` or `fprintf`:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%d", (int) mypid);
```

Comment: By the way, the `fprintf` only works if `pid_t` is in fact `signed int`.  Probably safer to cast it.